# I am using the Android Template Navigation Drawer Activity but if I change the title and add Fragments, if I click it doesn''t take me to the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I open a new Activity using Android template for Navigation Drawer Activity.
When I click on the default Navigation drawer it shows the different fragment.

I have changed the title of the options in Navigation Drawer.
But if I click on then, it doesn't take me to the Fragment.

I cannot find any itemSelected or onClick methods in the Main Activity of the template where I can change the code to show new Fragments.
Please help how can I adjust the code to get my own fragments.

'''

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_order, R.id.nav_status)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, 
        R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, 
        mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is 
       present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, 
     R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

```
//First set Navigation Item Selected listener 

navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

//then override the onNavigationItemSelected method like this..
 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.home:
               //do something...
                break;
            case R.id.about:
                 //do something...
                break;



        }
```

Comment: I am not clear that how shall I override the methods public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item). My Main Activity is just a blank container to navigate to different Fragments. So in switch statement I can't add the Fragment to Activity by transaction.add() method. As I am not adding fragment to Main Activity but only displaying the Fragment in screen. Please help in suggesting what could be code. Also, when I opened the Activity, the clicks on default options worked and fragment changed, even though I didn;t find any method implemented. So, I am confused how it worked